# Boost final score after should clause in mongodb atlas search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have few fields in which I want to search for users like: username, fullname, about, desgination.

Apart from this some of the users are marked as { type: 'EXPERT' }

Now my query looks like this:

```
    const docs = await this.userModel
      .aggregate()
      .search({
        index: 'User',
        count: { type: 'total' },
        compound: {
          should: [
            {
              text: {
                query: searchQuery,
                path: 'fullname',
                fuzzy: { prefixLength: 2 },
                score: { boost: { value: 5 } },
              },
            },
            {
              text: {
                query: searchQuery,
                path: 'username',
                fuzzy: { prefixLength: 2 },
                score: { boost: { value: 3 } },
              },
            },
            {
              text: {
                query: searchQuery,
                path: 'designation',
                fuzzy: { prefixLength: 2 },
                score: { boost: { value: 5 } },
              },
            },
            {
              text: {
                query: searchQuery,
                path: 'about',
                fuzzy: { prefixLength: 2 },
                score: { boost: { value: 1 } },
              },
            },
            {
              text: {
                query: 'EXPERT',
                path: 'type',
                score: { boost: { value: 5 } },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      })
```

Now this works fine until I search something rubbish like 'XYZ' and the { type: "EXPERT" } still comes on top.

What I want instead is to search in the fields: username, fullname, designation, about. And the searchQuery must match atleast one of the fields and if does match then apply the boost in the final results if any of the user in final results is of type 'EXPERT'

Comment: I suspect the issue is that it is doing a fuzzy match and matching the 'xyz' to something in your data.  Have you tried turning fuzzy off?